# Boost regex token iterator: getting input between parentheses

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm using the following function with Boost::tr1::sregex_token_iterator

```
int regexMultiple(std::string **s, std::string r)
{
    std::tr1::regex term=(std::tr1::regex)r;
    const std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator end;
    int nCountOcurrences;

    std::string sTemp=**s;

    for (std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator i(sTemp.begin(),sTemp.end(), term); i != end; ++i)
    {
        (*s)[nCountOcurrences]=*i;
        nCountOcurrences++;
    }
    return nCountOcurrences;
}
```

As you can suppose, `**s` is a pointer to a string, and r is the regex in question. This function works (in fact, *this* one *might* not work because I modified it from the original just to make it simpler, given that the rest is not relevant to the question).

What I want to know is, given, for example, a regex of this kind: `"Email: (.*?) Phone:..."`, is there any way to retrieve only the **(.*?)** part from it, or should I apply substrings over the given result to achieve this instead?

Else, it's going to throw out: Email: myemail@domain.com Phone: ..

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `regex_search`? You get all the capture groups returned to you in a nice package. Or do you want arbitrarily many capture groups? Also, `**s` is not a pointer to a string, it's a string (and `s` is a pointer to a pointer to a string) -- why not use references?

Comment: Looks like I've been doing it the wrong way, right? I'll look into that function. Thanks.

Comment: I think this should have a simple solution, let me reread your question. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Kerrek SB regex_search was the way to go. Using a loop and returning what[1] (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) got me what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Oh OK, cool! Why not post your solution as an answer, so we know what you've done? (It's OK to accept your own answers!)

Answer (score 2):

Should use regex_search like `Kerrek SB` recommended instead: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html

```
int regexMultiple(std::string **s, std::string r)
{
    std::tr1::regex term=(std::tr1::regex)r;
    std::string::const_iterator start, end;
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
    int nCountOcurrences=0;

    std::string sTemp=**s;
    start=sTemp.begin();
    end=sTemp.end();
    boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default; 

    while (regex_search(start,end, what, term, flags))
    {
        (*s)[nCountOcurrences]=what[1];
        nCountOcurrences++;
        start = what[0].second;
        flags |= boost::match_prev_avail;
        flags |= boost::match_not_bob;
    }

    return nCountOcurrences;
}
```

Comment: Cool. You could simplify the code a lot just syntactically, though. Let me know if you'd like some pointers.

Comment: Sure. Although that's not the final code on my end, there are a few things that I've added/removed

Comment: Should I append a version into the post?

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it-- it would be much better IMO

Comment: Hm, I'm unsure about passing the `string**` in and then mixing iterators... how do you call this function?

Comment: Actually, it sends in a pointer to a pointer with a string, then returns a pointer to a pointer that can point to 1 or an array of strings with the ocurrences -- I can't say it has much sense, but it was what I needed in the ocassion :P

Comment: Hang on, that sounds terribly dangerous. Is `*s` an array of strings? How do you know its size? How can you access `(*s)[nCountOccurrences]` safely?

Comment: Well, the function returns the array size (nCountOcurrences), so I don't think there could be much trouble. Also, *s gets deleted in it as to prevent memleak. It just switches from string to ocurrences strings.

Comment: @KerrekSB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1487/discussion-between-filgera-and-kerrek-sb)